# File size after cut

Tags: files, cut, size

I am trying to verify if I split large file correctly into multiple pieces. As an toy example, I have a file `out_sample`:

```
123456789012
123456789012
123456789012
123456789012
123456789012
```

This has 64 bytes when stored. When I split this file into six pieces using cut, the resulting files have 15 bytes each:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME="out_sample"
cut -c1-2 $FILENAME > a
cut -c3-4 $FILENAME > b
cut -c5-6 $FILENAME > c
cut -c7-8 $FILENAME > d
cut -c9-10 $FILENAME > e
cut -c11-12 $FILENAME > f
```

In total it means 6*15=90 bytes. What is the difference of 26 bytes between size of the original file and sum of sizes of the new files? I noticed that `cut` appends newline at the end of file, this would probably be 1 byte per file? What about the rest?

Comment: Your first file has 13 chars on each line (that is 12 chars + newline) so 5*13=65. Your pieces have 3 chars on each line (that is 2 chars + newline) so 3*5=15. The difference is that you have 6 pieces so you have an additional number of 5*5 newlines (that is 25, which added to 65 equals 90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cut 2 columns out of a file, `cut` adds a newline on each line. Therefore each output file consist of 5 lines, with 2 numbers and a newline each.
That explains 25 extra bytes (file one to five; the sixth file got just the newlines added you throw away by cutting column 13 out (newline in the input file)).
There is the last byte comming from? I assume you used an editor that does not force a newline at the very last line of your input file.

So nothing is missing.

Answer (score 1):

For this application you probably want to use `split` rather than `cut`. `split -b 15 $FILENAME` should work. It does the bookkeeping automatically, rather than making you calculate file offsets yourself.

EDIT: Misread the question; the `split` command doesn't split columnwise, just as chunks out of the byte stream. If you really want columnwise, the OP's approach is probably the best available.

Comment: Huh?  How can you get `split` to split a file column-wise?  The command you gave doesn't do anything like the commands that the question is about.